# How to label a dropdown so first item is not the label and possibly having a input field inside

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I would like this dropdown box to have a label "select so and so..." and when the user pressed the carret, the dropdown list is displayed and the first item on that list be a blank selection not the label name. How would i accomplish this? Is there a way to put a input box inside? The dropdown is basically a operator selector, " =, <,>" and a dollar amount. Such that when I do this it will search SQL for the a requisition for a dollar amount equal to, less than, or greater than the amount selected.

```
<select class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" style="width: 100px" ng-model="selectedOperator">
   <option label="Amount"></option>
   <option value="=">equal to</option>
   <option value="<">less than</option>
   <option value=">">greater than</option>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input class="form-control" type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use bootstraps dropdowns to do this. You just have to make sure that the dropdown-menu will not close as soon as the input field will get focus.

Here is an example, sure you'll get the idea.

```js
// get the needed elements.
var dd = $('#dd'),
    oprtrBtns = $('a[data-operatorType]');


function oprtrBtnsHndl () {
  var crntOprtr = $(this).attr('data-operatorType'),
      amount = $('#amount').val();

  // do what ever needs to be done.
  $('.output').text('select * from table where foo ' + crntOprtr + ' ' + amount);

}

// listen for the dropdown hide event 
dd.on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
  var $amountInput = $(this).find('#amount');
  
  // making sure the dropdown-menu will not close
  // when focusing the input field.
  if($amountInput.is(":focus")) {
    return false;
  }
  
});

// add click handler to your dropdown-menu buttons.
oprtrBtns.on('click', oprtrBtnsHndl);
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 0 12px;
}

a[data-operatorType] {
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="dropdown" id="dd">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          Select
          <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li class="dropdown-header">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
              <input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount" value="">
            </div>      
          </li>
          <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-operatorType="=">equal to</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-operatorType="<">less than</a></li>
          <li><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-operatorType=">">greater than</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <p class="output well text-muted text-center"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you should hook up the built-in `Bootstrap` events. See http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-methods

I think that what you want is way beyond the scope of the `dropdown` component. I'd recommend instead to focus on a different approach e.g. popping up a `modal` filled in with controls.